# How to access ListViewItems when DataType is set in DataTemplate of ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I'm working on a UWP app. I want to iterate through all the ListViewItems of a ListView in a page. Here's the xaml for the ListView.

```
<ListView x:Name="DownloadTaskListView"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.CompletedDownloads}"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Background="{x:Null}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:DownloadTask">
                    <Grid x:Name="ItemViewGrid" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="4,0,0,0">
                    ....
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

I use this piece of code to achieve this.

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in DownloadTaskListView.Items)
{
     // Do something useful

}
```

But it gave me an Exception. Because I set the DataType of DataTemplate so runtime throw me an exception that it cannot convert from from DownloadTask (In this case the data type) to the ListViewItem. So I want to ask what is the other way of accessing ListViewItems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ItemsControl.ContainerFromItem method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.containerfromitem.aspx) to find container corresponding to the specified item, then get the root element of this container, in your case it's a `Grid`. For example like this:

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in DownloadTaskListView.Items)
    {
        var listviewitem = item as DownloadTask;
        var container = DownloadTaskListView.ContainerFromItem(listviewitem) as ListViewItem;
        var ItemViewGrid = container.ContentTemplateRoot as Grid;
        //TODO:
    }
}
```

Just be aware that if you want to use this method in `SelectionChanged` event of your listview, you can just pass the selected Item into `ContainerFromItem` method, otherwise it will not find the `ListBoxItem`.

I should say, if it is possible, using data binding is better.

Comment: Thanks Grace, It works. I'm new in development, will tie up loose ends :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting ItemsSource as **ViewModel.CompletedDownloads** do the Item loop on the same.

```
foreach(var Items in ViewModel.CompletedDownloads)
{
    //Do Something Useful.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond, but I don't want to iterate through data source, I want to loop through ListViewItem which represents the UI to do stuff like setting visibility and IsSelected property so on.